# How to get the label field from filled pdf file created using open office in java

Tags: java, pdf

I have a pdf expro file with number of fields and it also contains the data in it.
I want to retrieve the label field.

[image]

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath+fileName);
                AcroFields form = reader.getAcroFields();



                Set<String> fldNames = form.getFields().keySet();

                for (String fldName : fldNames) {
                  System.out.println( fldName + ": " + form.getField( fldName ) );
                  fieldInPdf.add((fldName+"|"+form.getField( fldName )));

                }
```

I have written this code to get the field details in expro.However I am unable to get the label field.

Answer (score 0):

Try PrintFields example program from the source code [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/fdf/PrintFields.java.html) or [here](https://apache.googlesource.com/pdfbox/+/35025f10c2f5fff264a0b42a73e1d7133fd1c41b/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/fdf/PrintFields.java)?

If the data you want didn't show up, then try the command line application PDFDebugger. It shows what's available. If you don't see it, then it doesn't exist.